# command for counting number of active cron jobs in crontabs

Tags: shell-script, cron

#### Problem statement

I have 5 solaris boxes, some have Solaris 10 and some have Solaris 9.
All of them have many cronjobs in their crontabs.

I would like to know number of active cronjobs available, so I manually count the [cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

*Now I am looking for a command [bash shell I am using] to count the number of active cronjobs.*

I have tried `crontab -l|wc -l`, but my crontab contains many comments lines which are also counted with my command.
[image: crontab]

#### What I have tried

```
crontab -l|wc -l
```

#### What I am expecting

A bash shell command to count the number of active cronjobs (excluding comments lines).

Comment: Which `cron` implementation are you using? Some of them allow directives like `@daily` or `@hourly`, which also define jobs.

Comment: @ manatwork Im a newbee,I dont understand ur statement,I did not use @daily like commands.

Comment: This days most of the `cron`s are actually improved rewrites of `cron`, like `anacron`, `dcron`, `fcron`, `mcron`. They are all compatible with the original one, but usually they add something new too, by introducing directives with proprietary syntax. Anyway, if you use no directives, you can safely ignore my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete everything that does not start with a digit (the minute). But to get that, remove any leading whitespace first.  This will get rid of comments, blank lines, variable assignments, etc.

```
crontab -l 2>/dev/null | sed 's/^ *//;/^[*@0-9]/!d' | wc -l
```

Comment: What about entries starting with a `*` or `@`?

Comment: Correct, I missed the "*".  Thanks.

Comment: I would add `2>/dev/null` to the first command, so if there no job, then no error output.

Answer (score 2):

Why remove characters? Try the following:

```
$ crontab -l | grep -c "^[0-9*]"
```

Comment: says **illegal option  -p** on my solaris box

Comment: This would be my preferred way, but the minute can be “*” or “*/5” too, which would be missed by your expression.

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman note it's a big P , can you try again ?

Comment: @manatwork , thanks , i've updated my answer

Comment: actually it was my typo I tried big P only

Comment: @AaronLewis, either `^[\d*]` or `^(\d|\*)`. As you wrote you allow the literal “|” character in the character class. But `^[0-9*]` would be better, to get rid of the `-P` dependency.

Comment: @manatwork my mistake , thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

```
crontab -l | grep -v '^#'
```

Simple.

The number?

```
crontab -l | grep -v '^#' | wc -l
```

or

```
crontab -l | grep -c -v '^#'
```

(last one inspired by an answer here).

This will give you the (number of) scheduled cron jobs, not the active cron jobs, which could mean the jobs that are currently running.

Comment: This counts empty lines, lines with an indented comment, and lines containing environment variable definitions.

Answer (score 0):

after multiple attempts I have got below command.

```
crontab -l |sed -e '/#/d'|wc -l
```

more on [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

more on [wc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_%28Unix%29)

Comment: I believe that '/#/d' would remove valid lines that happen to have a comment at the end.

Comment: though my solution works for my requirement,urs is more solid

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH`:$PATH # needed on Solaris to get POSIX compliant versions
                          # of the basic Unix utilities

crontab -l | LC_ALL=C grep -c '^[[:blank:]]*[0-9@*]'
```

That is count the lines that start with either ASCII decimal digits or `*` or `@` (the latter not currently supported by Solaris `cron` but supported by a few other implementations) preceded by 0 or more blanks (in the C locale, that's either SPC or TAB).